# Download a table generated by linq query to PDF file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table formed from linq query in an ASP.NET MVC environment, I need to download it as a `.pdf` file.

This is my first question: I work with ASP.NET MVC applications and I need your help to do this task of downloading a table in multiple pages into `.pdf` file. I used this script but it only print the current page :

```
<script>
   var Printer = new Object();
   Printer.Print = function (HTML) {
     var win = window.open("")
     window.focus();
     win.document.title = "Apercu de l'impression en cours";
     win.document.body.innerHTML = HTML;
     win.print();
     win.close();
   }
   window.top.Printer = Printer;
```

This is the code of my application, controller:

```
public ActionResult besoins(string critere = null,int page = 1, string chaine = null)
{
      int valeur;
      IPagedList temp = null;
      var commande_interne = temp;

      if (critere == "tous")
      {
          commande_interne = db.Commande_interne.Include("Livraison_interne").Include("UserProfile")
                                 .Where(u => u.valideeParDirecteur == true && u.isActive == true)
                                 .OrderBy(u => u.traitee)
                                 .ToPagedList(page, 15);

      }
      else if (critere == "livre")
      {
          commande_interne = db.Commande_interne.Include("Livraison_interne").Include("UserProfile")
                 .Where(r => r.id_liv != null && r.valideeParDirecteur == true && r.isActive == true)
                 .OrderBy(u => u.traitee)
                 .ToPagedList(page, 15);
      }
      else if (critere == "nnlivre")
      {
          commande_interne = db.Commande_interne.Include("Livraison_interne").Include("UserProfile")
                .Where(r => r.id_liv == null && r.valideeParDirecteur == true && r.isActive == true)
                .OrderBy(u => u.traitee)
                .ToPagedList(page, 15);
      }
}
```

View markup:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Besoins";
<style>
    table.well {
        background-color:#fff;
    }
</style>
}
@Html.Partial("_CommandesInternes",Model)

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/formAjax")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/btnCriteres")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/btnToolTip")
}
```

I need to download all data in table in one pdf file , the script I used only prints the current page.

Comment: it's a good project, but it is probably too broad of a question.  There are multiple concepts you have to be introduced to to understand the task of producing a pdf from data and respond with an attached response in a WebApi, and how to facilitate that in the front end.. and of course there are various suggestions on how to do that...

Comment: as an alternative, you should consider reviewing css print styling.  the act of doing a print in your code sample invokes printing options, a typical option (selected by the user) is to print to File as a PDF file.  thus, you'll just look to support representing the DOM document with styling in that respect. i.e. `width:6.25in;padding:1in;margin:0;` etc etc

Comment: my familiarity is actually fairly limited with ways to generate pdf files - I've only ever used licensed frameworks as integrations.  I'm mostly familiar with crystal reports, both rpt and rdf; and iTextSharp as it relates to pdfForm fill behavior against template pdf files.  And FASTNXT as a DTD publishing solution that became part of Sharepoint in the 90s.   I would recommend one that supports XML to PDF conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Table is more or less an html, so You can use the Free Html To Pdf Converter from SelectPdf (http://selectpdf.com/community-edition/). It has a very good documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NuGet Package name "iTextSharp" (Install-Package iTextSharp -Version 5.5.13.1) for the Html to pdf convertion. Using this you can format your pdf and download it on client side.